# Devolver una lista de elementos que implementan una interfaz en java

Tags: java, arraylist

estoy haciendo una practica y me piden que codifique un método para que devuelva una lista que incluya solo los elementos que implementa una interfaz que tenemos (Movimiento).

El código que he hecho es este:

```
public List<Elemento> getElementosMovimiento(){
    List<Elemento> elemento= new ArrayList <Elemento>();
    for(Elemento elementoMovimiento: elemento) {
        if(elemento instanceof Movimiento) {
            elemento.add(elementoMovimiento);
        }

    }
    return elemento;

}
```

Pero no me funciona, no se si se me escapa algo al nivel sintaxis.

Gracias

Un saludo

Comment: Agrega cual es el error o mensaje mostrado, es importante, revisa [ask] y agrega detalles, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Quizá sea porque tu arreglo no tiene elementos, pero en este ejemplo claramente funciona.

```
   public List<Movimiento> getElementosMovimientos() {
        Object elemento0 = new Elemento();
        Object elemento1 = new Elemento();
        Object elemento3 = new Object();
        Object elemento4 = new Object();
        List<Object> elementos = new ArrayList<>();
        elementos.add(elemento0);
        elementos.add(elemento1);
        elementos.add(elemento3);
        elementos.add(elemento4);
        List<Movimiento> elementosMovimiento = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Object o: elementos) {
            if (o instanceof Movimiento) {
                elementosMovimiento.add((Movimiento)o);
            }
        }
        return elementosMovimiento;
    }
```